# Is phrase "for the love of design" correct?

Tags: phrase-choice

I have a question regarding phrase "for the love of design"
Is it gramatic/semantically correct?

I want to use this phrase as engraving on some project and it's supposed meaning is to be "I did this because I love designing"

English is my second language so please feel free to propose some other phrase if you think that it could be more fitting than what I proposed

Comment: Absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very poetic way to say 'because I love designing'.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing grammatically wrong with your phrase. However, It doesn't convert the exact idiomatic meaning you want to get across unless you explain it, which is fine in my opinion since it makes it somehow mystical.